# Can't see the source code with the new Etherscan user interface?

Tags: etherscan, contract-verification

everyone! A few days ago, Etherscan has updated their user interface - and now I have no idea, how to get the verified contract's source. Before it was located no the `#readContract` tab, but now there's a list of static methods.

[image]

Have you met this problem? And how did you solve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a link on the right-hand side  (in "Profile Summary") labeled "Contract". Click that, and then, assuming there's verified code available, you should see a tab for the contract's code.

(You should end up at 
https://etherscan.io/address/0xa74476443119A942dE498590Fe1f2454d7D4aC0d#code.)